# Update multiple fields in password protected MS word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have word document which has multiple fields. We are using ASK field and LINK Excel.sheet.12 (for some data extract from Excel to Word). In my word document, there is also some Exceptions (for editing). Now my problem is

1. How to update my all fields in protected Restrict Editing Word Document.
2. I don't want to unprotect my document or share password to our users
3. After updating all fields, user can enable to edit in Exceptions area only rest of other part must have unable to edit

currently I am using this code

```
Sub ChangeLinkPath()
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ActiveDocument.Range
    rg.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeFieldCodes = True
    With rg.Find
        .Text = "<original path and file name>"
        .Replacement.Text = "<new path and file name>"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

But whenever I used this, it will showing run time error "4605" as my word document is password protected. Can anyone have solution for this ?

1. I want to update all fields in word document,
2. All the fields have to update in password protected mode

Comment: You will either need to enter the password, or remove the password to make the changes, which will require knowing the password. Is the problem that you do not know the password?

Comment: I have password but I dont want to share with our users, we have multiple computers which are connected with LAN and we are fetching data from Excel to Word. I made word document which have fields and I add password for unwanted editing from users in word document, hence password is must for document.

Comment: Well that code is going to have to have the password in it, so you will just have to hope the users don't know how to look at the code.